# DataGridView Loop Through

Tags: loops, datagridview

I'm trying to loop through a data grid view and collect pairs of values into a list. I'm getting incorrectly paired values. Any Ideas?

Thanks!!

| True False (Bool) | Point Codes (String) | Offset (String) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | Curb | 1 |
| False | Sw-Out | -1 |
| True | Crown | 0 |

```
        // collects a list of pointcodes and offsets by extracting data from the DataGridView. 
        public List<PontCodeAndOffsets> DataGridViewtoListByCorridor(string corridorname)
        {

            List <PontCodeAndOffsets> ListPCandO = new List<PontCodeAndOffsets>();

            // check for correct corridor
            foreach (DataGridView dgv in this.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>())
            {
                if (dgv.Name == corridorname)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
                        {
                            PontCodeAndOffsets PCandOffsets = new PontCodeAndOffsets();
                            if (row.Cells[1].Value != null && row.Cells[2] != null)
                            {    if (col.Name == "Point Codes")
                                {

                                    PCandOffsets.PointCode = row.Cells[1].Value as string;
                                }

                                else if (col.Name == "Offsets")
                                {
                                    PCandOffsets.Offset = (double)row.Cells[2].Value; ;
                                }
                            }
                            ListPCandO.Add(PCandOffsets);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return ListPCandO;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        // collects a list of pointcodes and offsets by extracting data from the DataGridView. 
    public List<PontCodeAndOffsets> DataGridViewtoListByCorridor(string corridorname)
    {

        List <PontCodeAndOffsets> ListPCandO = new List<PontCodeAndOffsets>();

        // check for correct corridor
        foreach (DataGridView dgv in this.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>())
        {
            if (dgv.Name == corridorname)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
                {
                        PontCodeAndOffsets PCandOffsets = new PontCodeAndOffsets();
                    if (row.Cells["Point Codes"].Value != null && row.Cells["Offsets"] != null)
                    {
                        if ((bool)row.Cells[0].Value == true)
                        {
                            PCandOffsets.PointCode = row.Cells["Point Codes"].Value as string;
                            PCandOffsets.Offset = (double)row.Cells["Offsets"].Value;
                            ListPCandO.Add(PCandOffsets);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ListPCandO;
    }
```